# Is PP&CG the right place to ask my question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is Programming Puzzles & Code Golf the right place to ask my question:

**Which programming or description language has the most / least reserved words?**

The question will have *rules* to limit the answers :).

### Rules:

1. The language is a

   - imperative,
   - declarative or
   - functional
     *programming language* (PL) or
2. a *description language* (DL).
3. The language can be a domain specific language (DSL).
4. A *reserved word* is a

   - keyword,
   - built-in function and
   - contextual reserved word.
5. A *keyword* is a word that can not be used as an identifier like `if`.
6. Built-in functions or procedures are functions built into the language and are not part of a library. The are always accessable in all scopes and can not be unloaded from the current scope. Example: `print`
7. Contextual reserved words are reserved words in a context. Outside of the context they can be freely used.

Example answer:

```
Language:   VHDL (Very High Speed Hardware Description Language)
Type:       Description Language
Keywords:   115
Built-ins:  0
Contextual: 0
---------------------------
Reserved words: 115
```

Comment: Related: [link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/write-the-longest-sentence-using-keywords-of-a-programming-language)

Comment: Its actually a question that is hard to answer.  What do you define as a "reserved word"?  [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) probably has the least (0), as only the length of the program matters.  As for most, it probably be Mathematica that has a builtin for *everything*.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I updated my question with rules. Reserved words is a sum. Because description languages like SVG have many tags, I would like to divide the answers into PL and DL types.

Comment: This challenge, as it stands is quite vague.  The problem is that it is very hard to categorize languages.  Also, submissions here have to have *code*.  A "language" as a submission doesn't count.  If you think you can surmount both of those challenges, then post it in the [sandbox](https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to receive feedback.

Answer (score 16):

## I do not think so.

This site is for [challenges and contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and your question does not seem to include any kind of challenge. You can fully answer this question yourself just by looking at the docs of the programming languages you want to consider.